# Google Cloud angular hosted site displays specified key does not exist

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-platform

My bucket is named [www.example.org](http://www.example.org) and it contains the following content:

```
| - app.yaml
| - dist 
|  - webapp-angular
|     - index.html
|     - other assets
|
```

This is an Angular application manually deployed.  Application was accessible before with domain forwarding to the Google url provided after you deploy the site.  However, I am trying to configure the site to be accessible via [www.mydomain.org](http://www.mydomain.org) and have run through [these](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) instructions.

My load balancer status looks green and active.  My SSL certificate also looks green and active.  I have the corresponding A record configured in my Godaddy account.  Yet when I attempt to access the website at [www.mydomain.org](http://www.mydomain.org), I get this:

```
404. That’s an error.

The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

If I try https://www.example.org I get this instead:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

Comment: Why do you have an `app.yaml` file in the bucket? Those files are only used to deploy to App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the  below steps are properly configured:

1. To point your domain to your load balancer, create an A record using your domain registration service.
2. If you added multiple domains to your SSL certificate, you must add an A record for each one, all pointing to the load balancer's IP address.
3. Is the GCS bucket  "Shared Publicly"? If not, fix that.
4. Once you have completed the first three comments of mine, go to your website [www.example.org/index.html](http://www.example.org/index.html)
5. If you want a different home page than index.html, use the MainPageSuffix feature.

For setting up the MainPageSuffix and Index page suffix please refer the below steps: [1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website)

You can assign an index page suffix, which is controlled by the MainPageSuffix property, and a custom error page, which is controlled by the NotFoundPage property. Assigning either is optional, but without an index page, nothing is served. when users access your top-level site.

1. In the Google Cloud Console, go to the Cloud Storage Browser page.
2. In the list of buckets, find the bucket you created.
3. Click the Bucket overflow menu (:) associated with the bucket and select Edit
   website configuration.
4. In the website configuration dialog, specify the main page and error page.
5. Click Save.